# Naming of variables in gawk when using gensub

Tags: awk

I am doing string substitution in `gawk`. The code below is a simplified version (the real `replacement` argument to `gensub` involves lots of `"\\1\\3\\2"`, which is why I can't use `sub`/`gsub`). My question is one of robustness: since I'm modifying the 1st field (`$1`) with `gensub`, can I store the output of `gensub` in the variable `$1`, or does this have potential to cause problems (in other contexts; it works fine in my code)?

```
# test data
$ printf "Header_1\tHeader_2\nHiC_scaffold_1_1234\t1234\nHiC_scaffold_2_7890\t7890\n" > input.txt
# code I'm using (works as expected)
$ gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"} FNR == 1 {next} \
>     {one = gensub(/HiC_scaffold_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+) ?/, "HIC_SCAFFOLD_\\2_\\1", "g", $1)} \
>     {print $2 "\t" one}' \
>     input.txt > output.txt1
# code I'm asking about (works as expected with these test data)
$ gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"} FNR == 1 {next} \
>     {$1 = gensub(/HiC_scaffold_([0-9]+)_[0-9]+ ?/, "HIC_SCAFFOLD_\\2_\\1", "g", $1)} \
>     {print $2 "\t" $1}' \
>     input.txt > output.txt2
$ head *txt*
==> input.txt <==
Header_1        Header_2
HiC_scaffold_1_1234     1234
HiC_scaffold_2_7890     7890

==> output.txt1 <==
1234    HIC_SCAFFOLD_1
7890    HIC_SCAFFOLD_2

==> output.txt2 <==
1234    HIC_SCAFFOLD_1
7890    HIC_SCAFFOLD_2
```

Comment: No you can't do that with `gensub()`

Comment: If you could do let us know your sample of input and expected output we may get better understanding of your question and could try to help you more then.

Comment: If you ask if you can `$3 = gensub()`, then yes, you can.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I've added the test data, but it's not really relevant. Both code examples work. The question is, will the second version break in specific situations?

Comment: @KamilCuk, sorry, I changed the variable names to make the test data easier to work with, but you are correct, the output of `gensub` can be saved to a variable named `$3` or `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you are asking for a bit of a review on the second code.

Can you assign a field? Yes, so `$1 = gensub(something)` is ok ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html)).

Potential issues? Yes: if $*n* doesn't exist, then you are creating it, and thus modifying $0 as well. You are doing it on $1, as far as I know, if a record exists ($0) then it must have at least one field ($1) - might be empty.

Another caveat would be if you were assigning to $0, but feels a little bit out of scope. Do not attempt to `$1 = $1` after your `gensub()`.

Finally, let's have a look at `gensub()`. If you provide no target to it, then it falls back to use $0. You are not doing so.

In the end, I cannot see a trivial situation where this can go wrong. Your code seems fine to me.